# Sentry Java Slack Notifications - Exclude warn

Tags: java, logging, notifications, slack, sentry

I just started using Sentry for Java (Logback).
I don't want to see events that have a `level==warning`. Is there any way to rectify this?
I didn't find any doc that could help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the filter that's in the documentation?

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
    <level>WARN</level>
</filter>
```

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/logback/